# Power Mock Code Coverage using Corbetura, Ant 1.8.2 with JDK 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, ant, code-coverage

I have searched for how to get coverage report for Corbetura for Power Mock Test Cases.
Found many answers for that, but still getting many issues.

I am using below configuration in my application:
**Java (JDK)** :   1.5.0_22
**Eclipse** :   Indigo
**Ant** :   1.8.2
**Corbetura Libraries** :   Tried with 2.1.1

(Still question which set of libraries to use ?)

Please help me on this.
**Note**: I am using JDK 1.5, I have found many links where it has mentioned configurations with JDK 1.6.

***One more thing***:
As of now I am not able to execute Ant script with *<cobertura-instrument>* tag.

Find below the build XML I am using.
I have removed some portion of build xml (I cannot share that due to confidentiality).

Please suggest what is the correct way, to do the code coverage report of Power Mock Test Cases using Corbetura and JDK 1.5 with Ant.

```
<project name="projName" basedir="." default="clean">
    <description>
           Project Desc
    </description>

    <!-- PROPERTIES -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="test.dir" location="test" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="testclasses.dir" value="${build.dir}/testclasses" />
    <property name="instrumentedclasses.dir" value="${build.dir}/instrumentedclasses" />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
    <property name="resources.dir" location="resources" />
    <property name="libs.dir" value="lib" />

    <property name="testReport.dir" location="testReport" />
    <property name="cobertura.reports.dir" location="codecoverage" />
    <property name="cobertura.datafile" value="${build.dir}/cobertura.ser" />
    <property name="project.name" value="${ant.project.name}" />

    <property name="cobertura.dir" value="D:\\corbetura_libs" />


    <!-- PATHS -->
    <path id="src.compile.classpath" description="classpath for compiling sources">
        <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <exclude name="**/junit*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="test.compile.classpath" description="classpath for compiling test-sources">
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <exclude name="**/cobertura-2.1.1.jar" />
            <exclude name="cobertura-dependencies/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="test.runtime.classpath" description="classpath for running junit-tests">
        <pathelement location="${testclasses.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${instrumentedclasses.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <exclude name="**/cobertura-2.1.1.jar" />
            <exclude name="cobertura-dependencies/*.jar" />
            <exclude name="cobertura-dependencies/hamcrest*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="cobertura.classpath" description="classpath for test-report">
        <fileset dir="${cobertura.dir}">
            <include name="cobertura*.jar" />
            <include name="cobertura-dependencies/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- taskdefs -->
    <taskdef classpathref="cobertura.classpath" resource="tasks.properties" />

    <!-- PREPARE -->
    <target name="prepare" description="creating the needed directories for build and test report">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${testReport.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${cobertura.reports.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${testclasses.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${cobertura.reports.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${testReport.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- COMPILE SOURCES -->
    <target name="compile.sources" depends="prepare" description="compile the source ">
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src.dir} into ${build.dir} -->
        <javac classpathref="src.compile.classpath" srcdir="${src.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.5" target="1.5" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" />

        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resources.dir}" includes="*.properties" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- CORBETURA INSTRUMENT CLASSES -->
    <target name="instrument.classes" depends="compile.sources">
        <cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumentedclasses.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.datafile}">
            <includeclasses regex=".*" />
            <instrumentationClasspath>
                <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
            </instrumentationClasspath>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>

    <!-- COMPILE TEST CASES -->
    <target name="compile.tests" depends="instrument.classes" description="compile test classes">
        <javac classpathref="test.compile.classpath" srcdir="${test.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" destdir="${testclasses.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false" />

        <copy todir="${testclasses.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resources.dir}" includes="*.properties" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- RUN TEST CASES -->
    <target name="run.tests" depends="compile.tests" description="execute junit test cases">

        <junit haltonfailure="false" printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes" fork="true">
            <!-- junit-specific -->
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath refid="test.runtime.classpath" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${testReport.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>

            <!-- cobertura-specific -->
            <sysproperty key="net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile" file="${cobertura.datafile}" />
            <classpath refid="cobertura.classpath" />
        </junit>

        <cobertura-report format="html" destdir="${cobertura.reports.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.datafile}" srcdir="${src.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- CREATE TEST CASE REPORT -->
    <target name="report" depends="run.tests">
        <junitreport todir="${testReport.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${testReport.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${testReport.dir}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>

 </project>
```

Comment: It worked for me, using JDK 1.5, Ant 1.9.4 And Corbetura Libs with Corbetura version 1.9.4.1.
The same build xml executed successfully.